# cname to map subdomain.domain1.com to domain2.com/subdomain

Tags: web, github, github-pages, subdomain

I am looking for a way to

use a cname or whatnot to map

```
subdomain.domain1.com
```

to

```
domain2.com/subdomain
```

is this possible and what is the best way to do it?

more specifically, I have a github.io page at

oresoftware.github.io/suman

and I own a GoDaddy domain at

```
collide.io
```

so I want to send

```
suman.collide.io
```

to

```
oresoftware.github.io/suman
```